# Get data without local cache

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

### Problem

In an Angular web app, I'm getting data from a collection, let's call this collection `lists`, I get one list (let's call it `list1` from this collection, using its key.

Later in the same app, I'm executing a query on this `lists` collection to get all the lists matching my criterias, let's say I want `authorId` key to be equal to my current `userId`.

But, the issue is that `list1` matches the criterias, so in the page showing the `lists` entries matching my criterias, I have two Observable emissions from my query, first being what matches from the `lists` entries I already fetched, and second one being what comes from server.

This is an issue because on the user's side, they see the loading animation, then one of their lists shows up (the one they already got from db), then all their lists show up.

Example query for this:

```
this.firestore.collection('lists', ref => ref.where('userId', '==', 'foo'))
```

### Already tried

using `skip(1)` operator on the data Observable, but this doesn't work because if I go right to this page without fetching another list first, then first emission is the one I want, and I'm skipping it, resulting in an infinite loader until someone or something edits one of the lists, triggering another emission from the `valueChange()` Observable.